# When is the composition operator assigned to a measure-preserving map unitary?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a standard probability space, and let $T:X\rightarrow X$ be a measurable, measure-preserving transformation, i.e. for every $A\in\mathcal{B}$, $\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$. Consider the operator $U_T:L_2(\mu)\rightarrow L_2(\mu)$ given by $U_T (f)=f\circ T$. Clearly it is a linear isometry. My question is whether $U_T$ is unitary.

Comment: For reference, the mapping $T\longrightarrow U_T$ is called the Koopman representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes when $T$ is invertible and with measurable inverse. In this case, $(U_T)^*=U_{T^{-1}}$ gives the adjoint.

More generally, in Peter Walters' book *An introduction to Ergodic theory*, we find the following result:

> **Theorem 2.8.** Let $T$ be a measure preserving transformation on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal B,\mu)$. Then $U_T\colon L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\mu)$ is surjective if and only if $M\colon (\widetilde{\mathcal B},\widetilde{\mu})\to (\widetilde{\mathcal B},\widetilde{\mu})$is surjective, where $\widetilde{\mathcal B}$ is $\mathcal B$ where we identify set $A$ and $B$ when $\mu(A\Delta B)=0$, $\widetilde{\mu}$ is defined canonically and $M(B)=T^{-1}(B)$.

If $U_T$ is bijective and $A\in\mathcal B$, let $f$ such that $U_Tf=\chi_{\widetilde A}$. Then $U_T(f\cdot f)=U_T(f)$ so $f\cdot f=f$ and $f=\chi_{\widetilde C}$ for some $C\in\mathcal B$. So $\widetilde A=M(\widetilde C)$ and $M$ is surjective.

The latter condition is not always satisfied, as [5PM](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53153/5pm) points out. Take $X=[0,1]$, $\mathcal B$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure and $T(x):=2x\operatorname{ mod }1$. In this case $U_T$ is not onto as the function which are not $1/2$-periodic are not in the range.

Comment: When $T$ is invertible it is clear. But if it is not invertible, what happens then?

Comment: So: we should show that if $T$ is not injective (a.e. or something), then not everything in $L_2$ can be written as $f \circ T$ a.e.  ...

Comment: In the book: "Recurrence in Ergodic Theory and Combinatorial Number Theory" by H. Furstenberg this operator $U_T$ is reffered to as a unitary operator and I didn't see an assumption that $T$ is invertible.

Comment: To pass from the noninvertible case to the invertible case, is it possible to just work on the natural extension of $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu, T)$?

Comment: @user25640 Could you give the page number? I don't own the book, but someone else may be able to identify any implicit additional assumption that the authors might have used there.

Comment: I've added additional information.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo Can you think of a measure-preserving transformation $T$ of a standard probability space such that the induced function $M$ is not surjective?

Comment: I will think about this. I will indeed make the theorem more useful.

Comment: @user25640 $T(x)=2x \mod 1$ is a measure-preserving transformation on $[0,1]$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure. That is, for every measurable set $E\subset [0,1]$ we have $|T^{-1}E|=|E|$. Only certain functions can be written as $u\circ T$: those that are $1/2$-periodic.

Comment: @Pavel It seems like a good example. Clearly some segments like $(0,0.5)$ for example are not in the image of $M$.