# Example of an ergodic transformation with some properties in the spectrum of the Koopman operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, dynamical-systems, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ a probability space, for simplicity we can assume $X$ a metric space. Let $T: (X,\mathcal{B},\mu) \to (X,\mathcal{B},\mu) $ be an invertible, measure-preserving transformation. We can now define the (linear) operator $U_T : L^2 (X,\mathcal{B},\mu) \to L^2(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ by the following formula:

$$U_T f = f\circ T \text{ for }f \in L^2(X,\mathcal{B},\mu).$$

I would like to know if there is any example of an operator $T$ satisfying the above hypotheses and

- $\mathbf{1}$ is a eigenvalue of $U_T$;
- the dimension of the eigenspace of $\mathbf{1}$ is $1$;
- the dimension of the generalized eigenspace of $\mathbf{1}$ is greater than $1$.

Notes:

1. The operator $U_T$ is known as the *Koopman Operator*;
2. This question arose because I have a doubt about the definition of *simple eigenvalue*, since it is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1778237/680679) that if $1$ is a simple eigenvalue of $U_T$, then $T$ is ergodic. In my head, there is a question whether the fact of being simple is talking about eigenspace or *generalized* eigenspace. In the [literature](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2384999/680679), I always see it being treated as the dimension of the eigenspace, so there should be an example satisfying the requirements of my question, but I haven't been able to come up with one.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such example.  This is because the Koopman operator $U_T$ is unitary and hence $1-U_T$ is normal.

If $\xi$ is a vector such that  $(1-U_T)^n\xi=0$, for some $n$, one would also have that $(1-U_T)\xi=0$.  Thus the generalized eigenspace coincides with the standard eigenspace.

---

EDIT:
The proof I had in mind for the fact that the generalized eigenspaces coincide with standard eigenspaces uses
the Spectral Theorem, but here is a more pedestrian argument:

**Lemma 1.** If  $T$ is a bounded, self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and if $\xi $ is a vector in $H$ such that
$T^2\xi =0$, then $T\xi =0$.

**Proof.** We have
$$
  \|T\xi \|^2= \langle T\xi ,T\xi \rangle = \langle T^*T\xi ,\xi \rangle =\langle T^2\xi ,\xi \rangle =0.
  $$
QED.

**Lemma 2.** If  $N$ is a bounded, normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and if $\xi $ is a vector in $H$ such that
$N^2\xi =0$, then $N\xi =0$.

**Proof.** By hypothesis
$$
  0 = (N^*)^2N^2\xi  = N^*N^*NN\xi = N^*NN^*N\xi  = (N^*N)^2\xi ,
  $$
so $N^*N\xi =0$, by Lemma 1.  Consequently,
$$
  \|N\xi \|^2= \langle N\xi ,N\xi \rangle = \langle N^*N\xi ,\xi \rangle =0.
  $$
QED.

**Lemma 3.** If  $N$ is a bounded, normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and if $\xi $ is a vector in $H$ such that
$N^q\xi =0$, for some integer $q>0$,  then $N\xi =0$.

**Proof.** Choose $p>0$ such that $p+q$ is a power of 2, say $p+q=2^k$.  Then
$$
  N^{2^k}\xi =
  N^pN^q\xi =0.
  $$
Observing that  $N^{2^k}$ is the square of the normal operator $N^{2^{k-1}}$, it follows from Lemma 2 that
$N^{2^{k-1}}\xi =0$, and then induction implies that $N\xi =0$,  as desired.  QED.

**Theorem.** If  $N$ is a bounded, normal operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and if $\xi $ is a generalized eigenvector of
$N$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda $, then
$\xi $ is an eigenvector of
$N$ for $\lambda $.

**Proof.** By definition,  there exists some integer $q>0$, such that $(N-\lambda )^q\xi =0$, so $(N-\lambda )\xi =0$, by Lemma 3.  QED

PS:  I wonder if there is a shorter, equally elementary argument for this...

Comment: If I remember, for $U_T$ to be unitary, it is enough for $T$ to be invertible, right?

Comment: Yes, if $T$ in measure preserving and invertible then $U_T$ is unitary (norm preserving and invertible).

Comment: Thanks!, I've always had doubts related to this definition, as in an algebraic context, I've usually seen the definition of being simple related to generalized eigenspace. So when I define simple eigenvalue (in ergodic theory), I can speak of the generalized eigenspace dimension, right?

Comment: Yes, for normal operators, eigenspace is the same as generalized eigenspace.

Comment: @Mrcrg $U_T$ is always unitary, even when $T$ is not invertible.

Comment: @AlpUzman Interesting, do you have any references for me to see?

Comment: @Mrcrg $\langle U_T(f),U_T(g)\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}= \int_X f\circ T(x)\, \overline{g\circ T(x)}\, d\mu(x) = \int_X f(x)\, \overline{g(x)}\, d T_\ast(\mu)(x)= \int_X f(x) \,\overline{g(x)} \,d \mu(x)= \langle f,g \rangle_{L^2(\mu)}$.

Comment: Similarly $U_T$ will be an isometry on $L^p$ spaces. If $T$ does not preserve $\mu$ but it's measure class (such $T$a re called non-singular in ergodic theory), then an appropriate Radon-Nikodym factor should be included.

Comment: @Alp, $U_T$ always preserves inner product (provided $T$ preserves measure) but it might not be unitary.  Consider the shift on the one-sided Bernoulli space!

Comment: @Ruy Thank you, I was mistakenly using "unitary" and "inner product preserving" synonymously, apologies.

Comment: The difference between "unitary" and "inner product preserving" was discussed before here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/265907/169085

Comment: @AlpUzman, indeed the difference is crucial since "unitary" implies "normal" but "inner product preserving" does not!

Comment: @Ruy I wonder if you know if the same is true for the Perron-Frobenius(P-F) operator? P-F and Koopman operators are related, but in the case of P-F it's not in a Hilbert space, so I couldn't apply the same reasoning.The relationship is $\int (P_T) g\,d\mu = \int f U_T g\,d\mu$ for $f\in L^1, g\in L^{\infty}$.  For more information you can see [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-85367-1_4.pdf).

Comment: Could you be more precise and give full definitions?  The chapter you link to costs 129 USD!

Comment: @Ruy Sorry, I was at university and didn't realize the material was paid. Would you like to [continue this discussion in chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136323/relation-between-the-generalized-eigenspace-and-the-eigenspace-of-the-perron-frob)